# Has many through relationship in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many, model-associations

I am using facebook api to fetch users from fb.

I want to store the users in my model `User`

I am using `has many through` relationship to store users

User model relationship I have in my `user` model.

```
has_many :friends, :through => :user_friends, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
```

`User friends` model intermediate table to fetch friends of a user.

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "friend_id"
```

User friends has `user_id` and `friend_id` columns I added those in migration.

I get an error when I use `.friends` on a user object.

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :user_friends in model User
```

can anyone help with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a many to many relationship between user and friends?

Comment: @RichaSinha :Yes like we have in social networks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check [Self-Referential Association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association). Apparently you are missing some concepts. You can not add 2 associations with the same name in a single model, (only one of them will respond).

You should add `has_many :user_friends`, but you will still be missing the other side of the association, check this example:

---

```
# user.rb
has_many :user_friends
has_many :friends, :through => :user_friends
has_many :inverse_friendships, :class_name => "UserFriend", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
has_many :inverse_friends, :through => :inverse_friendships, :source => :user
```

---

```
# user_friends.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
```

Comment: :Thanks a lot that worked basically I was missing `has_many :user_friends`. and model name I should have used `friend` in the second associations.

Answer (score 1):

Add `has_many :user_friends` before the `has_many :through` line

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

**User Model:**

```
has_many :user_friends
has_many :friends, :through => :user_friends, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
```

**Friends Model:**

```
  has_many :user_friends
  has_many :users, through: :user_friends
```

**User Friends Model**

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :foreign_key => "friend_id"
```